# How do I flash an AMI BIOS? Can I do it with a .bin file? (Razer Blade Laptop)

Tags: bios, updates, flash, downgrade

I have a Razer Blade 15" (2019) Advanced that has an AMI (American Megatrends) BIOS that I'm trying to downgrade because of some USB port issues. Downgrades using only Razer's provided BIOS updaters are not possible, so I have to resort to other procedures. There are guides on how to flash this BIOS but they require a .rom file which Razer's BIOS updater doesn't have. These are the files that the updater contains when extracted:

[image]

So the clearest procedure that I've found is to get an application called *afuwingui.exe* (the one I got was from https://ami.com/en/products/, an application called ***Aptio V*** that contains an executable *AFUWINGUIx64.EXE*. **Please confirm that this is the right one for the task**) and with this, flash the BIOS using a .rom file. However, as I said above, I have no .rom file.
There's this reddit post ([Click here](https://www.reddit.com/r/razer/comments/beh775/blade_advanced_2019_v104_bios_issues/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf) to see reddit post) that suggests that the file ***Charlotte2_0104.bin*** inside the Razer BIOS updater contains the BIOS image. Also, the *AFUWINGUIx64.EXE* that I have has an option to use a .bin file for flashing. Is it safe to use *Charlotte2_0104.bin* for this?

If there is another procedure that can accomplish the same thing, please enlighten me.

I apologize if this may seem like dumb question to ask, but I just need to be extra cautious so as to not brick my system. I would've tried any procedure that I find on the internet if I encountered no complications in these procedures, and if there were no grave consequences.

Comment: Honestly, without an SPI programmer and a BIOS dump, I wouldn't do this. `Charlotte2_0104.bin` is almost certainly the right file (sensible extension and 16 MiB size which would exactly match the BIOS flash chip), but it may not be in the right format. Also there may be some manufacturer-specific procedure that has to be applied besides flashing that a generic flasher won't carry out.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll just wait for the next BIOS update